# Already value for key datasource

Tags: spring, spring-batch, insertion

org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@278d31be] for key [HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1)] bound to thread [restartedMain]

while i am
Inserting data to table
I am getting the above listed error

Comment: Add some code where this error is occured

Comment: I am getting this error in afterWrite method of writer listener and I am using jpa to insert data .

Comment: ok looks like you are using JpaItemWriter for writing data. It would be great if you can share the code to debug it further.

Comment: public class TestItemWriterListener implements ItemWriteListener<Table> {
}

Comment: It is not helpful, can you share your code via Github or zip file?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.